# Typescript: Map string[] to [string, string]

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I map an string array `string[]` to a 2 dimensional array with strings `[string, string]`?

I tried

```
const animals: string[] = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse'];
// This throws an error
let splittedArray: [string, string] = animals.slice(0,2);

// This doesn't throw an error
// let splittedArray: [string, string] = ['Dog', 'Cat'];

// Error Message
// Type 'string[]' is missing the following properties from type '[string, string]': 0, 1 ts(2739)
```

My desired output should be:

```
console.log(splittedArray);
// ['Dog', 'Cat']
```

Comment: What you tried is not an 2D array of strings; it is a array with 2 *elements* of type string

Comment: I know, it is just an example. I really need an array with exactly 2 elements of type string.

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Comment: you need `animals.slice(0, 2)`... `0, 1` would give you just `['Dog']`

Comment: Still: `Type 'string[]' is missing the following properties from type '[string, string]': 0, 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change type declaration to this... The `as` operator's mostly designed for `*.tsx` files to avoid the syntax ambiguity.  Working [StackBlitz Link is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7116bi)

```
const animals: string[] = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse'];
let splittedArray = animals.slice(0,2) as [string,string];
console.log(splittedArray)
```

Comment: It works, perfect. Thank you! Still don't know what this cryptic error message means, but anyways. At least a solution for now

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a 2D array or an array with 2 elements? This seems to work for your output:

```
    const animals: string[] = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse'];
    let splittedArray: string[] = animals.slice(0,2);
```

Comment: I want an array with exactly 2 elements. `[string, string]`

Comment: Then my answer till work it will give you the output of : ['Dog', 'Cat']

Comment: That's what my question is about. I know how to extract 2 elements from an array. My question is to set the value of an array to an array with `[string, string]`

Comment: Why the downvote? the reason for your error message is because animals.slice(0,2) is of type String[]. You can not write [string, string]. If you splice at index 0 with 2 element you get an array with 2 elements, starting from index 0. Is that not what you want?